# Learning near a dead body

Tags: halacha, torah-study, death

May a person learn torah near a dead body? Does it matter if the corpse is Jewish or not? Please cite sources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[*Gesher Hachayim*, chapter 5, section 2, paragraphs 1–4](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=31174&pgnum=50), writes (in my own loose translation):

> And one is not allowed to speak words of Torah within four cubits of a corpse, or even read *Sh'ma* or pray or say a *b'racha*, for he'd be "teasing the pauper", doing a *mitzva* that the dead person cannot. Likewise, he can't be in the vicinity of the corpse wearing *t'filin* or *tzitzis* visible out.
>
> Outside of the corpse's four cubits it's permitted. The *Shach* wrote that words of Torah are prohibited even outside of four cubits, but the later rabbis have taken the position that even words of Torah are permitted outside four cubits.
>
> But in the house the corpse is in, we're stringent even outside of his four cubits, as we treat the whole house as four cubits.
>
> Even before a woman's or minor's corpse, who were exempt from Torah study, *tzitzis*, and *t'filin* even when alive, we nonetheless are forbidden to study or be adorned by *t'filin* or *tzitzis*.
>
> But we can say, before a corpse, psalms or other things and verses that portend raising the level of his soul... and such verses as are customary to say when washing or dressing him [in preparation for burial]. For by such... "teasing the pauper" is irrelevant....
>
> Also to expound before the corpse things in his honor (even as the *S'faradim* do) is permitted, as anything for his honor is permitted.

As always, for practical *halacha*, consult your rabbi rather than relying on what you read on this site. Note that the *Gesher Hachayim* does not specifically (as far as I see) mention non-Jews' corpses, one way or the other.

Comment: How does this reconcile with the custom for the person doing *shmira* over an unburied *niftar* to recite tehillim while doing the *shmira*?

Comment: @eykanal, See the second to last paragraph in the quoted section.

Comment: Thank you for this helpful answer. 

It would seem from the Gesher Hachayim says that this prohibition should only apply to a Jewish corpse because it falls under the category of lo'eg l'rosh, were we are concerned about 'mocking' the neshama who no longer has a chance to perform these mitzvos (even if not obligated like the woman or child) but a gentile is in fact forbidden to learn and thus should be precluded.

Comment: @Moshe, I agree with the gist of your comment, but CYLOR for practical guidance.

Comment: RAMBAM Mishneh Torah Hilchos Avel Ch. 14 could be the source for Gesher HaChaim.